# Get html input type value in lightning JS controller

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am stuck with one issue regarding lightning components, I am using

`<input type="date" aura.id="Wellness Visit" class="inpText" format="MM/dd/yyyy" value="{!v.visitDate}" />` element

Calendar is appearing but not able to get the value in controller.

```
var inputDate = component.find("Wellness Visit").get("v.value"); 
console.log('*****inputDate****'+inputDate);
```

Getting undefined in the log

Please suggest any other way i can get the html elament value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Aura input component instead of html tag,

```
    <ui:inputDate aura.id="Wellness Visit" class="inpText" format="MM/dd/yyyy" value="{!v.visitDate}" />
```

For more you can read here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputDate.htm

Comment: Yes that's fine but the issue is that lightning datepicker is not looking good and it's size is too big. Is there anyway to decrease the calendar size?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @chinmayahd,

Finally i got the solution here,

[enter link description here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/99599/lightning-uiinputdate-component-does-not-inherit-style-from-design-system)

Check answer given by Boog, i am using

You can check the following screenshot.
[image]